# Reading File from Same server

Tags: php, file-get-contents, readfile

I want to read a PHP file located on the same server as the script. Yet, I want to read it as if it is from another server so that it views the HTML output of the file.

But when I read the file using `file_get_contents()` I just get the PHP Code.

NOTE: if this helps, I`m printing the contents of the file to fckEditor.

Comment: What are you passing to file_get_contents()?

Comment: @Jim Lewis: I`m passing the .php file.

Comment: I was hoping you'd show the actual line of code. Are you passing it as a pathname, a file: URL, or an http: URL?  I'd expect the first two options to return the source code, and the final option to return the HTML output you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use curl

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

$x=get_web_page('http://yourserver/the_script.php');

echo $x["content"];

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read it, just include it using `include()`, for example:

```
$includefile="path/to/file.php";
if (file_exists($includefile)) 
    include($includefile);
```

EDIT:

if you need to assign the output to a variable, use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`

```
ob_start();
include($includefile);
$out = ob_get_clean();
```

Looking at the FCKeditor site, you would use it like this:

```
$FCKeditor->Value = $out;
```

Comment: Wimmel: I don`t want to include it, I want the user to be able to edit it using the fckEditor. so including the file won`t help.

Comment: @sikas, I'm not familiar with fckEditor, but I modified my response, hoping that this is what you mean.

Comment: the update didn`t work, as there is an included file in both.